# Add/keep black slashes to json dumps for API request

Tags: python, json

I am working with an API that is weird. It accepts json but the object inside seems to be a stringed version of a listed object with slashes. In order to post the correct information to there server I would have to mimick this setup.

Take for example this request 's POST Object:

```
{"data":"[{\"type\":\"Hosting.Library.SpamStopper.Public.Operations.Module.GetEmailManagementLinksOperation\",\"operation\":{\"State\":0}}]","charge":true}
```

notice how it LOOKS like an Object>list>Object but inreality its a Object>stringified version of List>Object

I want to know how I can Programmably write out the same type of request dynamically.

So, for example, how can I change the State to 1?

I could say something like:

```
test = {"data":"[{\"type\":\"Hosting.Library.SpamStopper.Public.Operations.Module.GetEmailManagementLinksOperation\",\"operation\":{\"State\":0}}]","charge":True}
testchange = json.loads(test["data"])
testchange[0]["operation"]["State"] = 1
print(testchange)
```

but then how do I convert it back so I can send off the request?

Comment: Based on what you say, the API expects strings. Both backslashes and nested quotes would need escaped.

Comment: _However it failed and came out without the slashes_ - Because you never used `testjson` there.

Comment: @OneCricketeer That was an error. The same code comes out if I use `testjson`. I tried it just now and got the same error exactly. I changed the OP to fix the code. 

Also the API expects EXACTLY what I wrote at the top first: `{"data":"[{\"type\":\"Hosting.Library.SpamStopper.Policies.Public.Operations.GetPoliciesOperation\",\"operation\":{\"State\":0}}]","charge":True}` It needs all the slashes BUT if you notice, the object isn't a string, its an object but the data inside seems to be somestring converted json of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you will be able to perform what you are trying to do, since the python interpreter is going to absorb those single black-slashes `\`.

I had similar problems with APIs very specific with their JSONs. I was able to fix the problems being sure that my headers explicitly state my `"Content-Type: application/json"` and/or using something like this:

```js
testjson = json.dumps(testdata).encode("utf-8")
```

I hope this helps you somehow.
Also, if you could provide some API examples where we could do some testing, or any information about the technology this backend is running, we could try to help you more.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue which I will write a post about but yeah....this API is super weird. Its not a public API so it makes sense BUT, the rest of the website doesn't accept there objects with slashes so I don't know who decided to do it that way. lol I was able to figure it out by add the slashes back during the `json.dumps` I was going to up vote this but I am too low to upvote still.

Comment: Don't worry about it :D. Glad you could make it happen, congrats 

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer:

```
test = {"data":"[{\"type\":\"Hosting.Library.SpamStopper.Public.Operations.Module.GetEmailManagementLinksOperation\",\"operation\":{\"State\":0}}]","charge":True}
testchange = json.loads(test["data"])
testchange[0]["operation"]["State"] = 1
test["data"] = json.dumps(testchange).replace('"',r'\"')
print(test)
```

The idea is to put the slashes back once I am done with the object and use json.dumps to stringify the object. Very weird api but maybe useful if I run across something like this again.